# Trying to create multiple views from one XIB file programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios7, xib

I have a page enabled scroll view which I would like to fill with `UIViews`. I have tried creating a "XIB" file and loading from it in a for loop, but this only gives me one `UIView` in my scroll view.

```
    int amount = garments.count;
[self.pageControl setNumberOfPages:amount];

for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    DOVGarment *garment = garments[i];

    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    DOVGarmentDetailView *view = [DOVGarmentDetailView new];

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"detailView" owner:view options:nil];

    view = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];

    view.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:garment.fileName];
    view.labelID.text = garment.ID;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:view];
}

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * amount, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

Anyone have an idea why this doesn't work? Or if this is even possible?

Comment: You are creating multiple views but you are not changing the frame so they will all be placed directly on top of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating multiple views but you are not changing the frame so they will all be placed directly on top of each other.

Update your code to offset each view relative to the one created before

Answer (score 2):

Every view object you place in your xib file has only one instance of it. So every run cycle of your for loop you are accessing the same UIView instance. 
Incase you need to fill your scrollView with view's you need to alloc and initialise again in every run cycle of the for loop thereby creating many instances of UIView.

This is how I did it which places UIViews horizontally in my scrollView -

```
for (int i = 0; i<numberOfViews; i++)

            {

                UIView*smallView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i*scrollview.frame.size.width+heightOfYourView), 0, scrollview.frame.size.width, scrollview.bounds.size.height)];
[scrollview addSubview: smallView];

             }
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(numberOfViews*scrollview.frame.size.width,    scrollview.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware of this solution, I am however looking for a way to generate multiple views that I can style similarly in a XIB. Do you have any insight?